# How to Trigger an function using text on a text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello community from stackoverflow, i have a question about how can we trigger a function from certain letters/numbers.
So the thing is:
-We have an image and a text box to write what is inside the image.
-When we see something in the text box ( like letter A or number 2 ), we "trigger" a .click on Collect Coins (Code Below).

So how can i do this. Because it would be really handy for me an Tampermonkey script that auto-click on the Butoon without me touching it.

CODE BELOW:

```
<form method="post" id="free-coins" class="info-box captcha-holder active">
<div class="padding">
<h2>Captcha protection</h2>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,TkSuQmCC" class="captcha">
<input type="text" name="captcha" placeholder="Write here">
<div class="btn-big"><button type="submit" class="btn">collect coins</button></div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What has or has not worked? You're gonna get hit with downvotes.

Comment: I don't have any knowledge on this. So I'm asking for help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery method ".change()" for the input and test with regex if matches the letter/numbers you want and then use the jQuery method ".click()" to click on the submit button

.change() method: https://api.jquery.com/change/

.click() method: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Das me uma ajuda sff, podes me re editar o script, é que eu nao tenho conhecimento nenhum disto sff.